# @fontface Quicksand Light for Mac/iPhone/iPad

Tags: css, macos, browser, font-face

i have installed webkit Quicksand Light and book in to my CSS file, its all working fine in all browsers on the PC however when i view it on a MAC in any browser the quicksand light web font doesnt display properly comes out like a times new roman type of font. Is it not picking up the font? or is it just not rendering?

cant find any solutions to this problem, been at it all day trying to fix it

CSS:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'QuicksandLight';
src: url('/assets/fonts/Quicksand_Light-webfont.eot');
src: url('/assets/fonts/Quicksand_Light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('/assets/fonts/Quicksand_Light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('/assets/fonts/Quicksand_Light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('/assets/fonts/Quicksand_Light-webfont.svg#QuicksandLight') format('svg');
     /*url('/assets/fonts/Quicksand_Light.otf');*/
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
font-family: 'QuicksandLightOblique';
src: url('/assets/fonts/Quicksand_Light_Oblique-webfont.eot');
src: url('/assets/fonts/Quicksand_Light_Oblique-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('/assets/fonts/Quicksand_Light_Oblique-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('/assets/fonts/Quicksand_Light_Oblique-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('/assets/fonts/Quicksand_Light_Oblique-webfont.svg#QuicksandLightOblique') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
font-family: 'QuicksandBook';
src: url('/assets/fonts/Quicksand_Book-webfont.eot');
src: url('/assets/fonts/Quicksand_Book-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('/assets/fonts/Quicksand_Book-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('/assets/fonts/Quicksand_Book-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('/assets/fonts/Quicksand_Book-webfont.svg#QuicksandBook') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}
```

CSS for QuicksandBook;

```
body
{
 font:13px/24px 'QuicksandBook', Arial,sans-serif;
 font-weight: normal;
 }
```

these have been referenced in the head section.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't have a Mac available to test on, but some of the pointers listed here might well be worth a shot.  Let us know how you get on!

http://paulirish.com/2010/font-face-gotchas/#smiley

Answer (score 0):

I normally load all of my font's at the very top of my css - I dont know if that makes a difference.

Also for future reference you can do your font's like this:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Quicksand';
src: url('/assets/fonts/Quicksand_Light-webfont.eot');
src: url('/assets/fonts/Quicksand_Light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('/assets/fonts/Quicksand_Light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('/assets/fonts/Quicksand_Light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('/assets/fonts/Quicksand_Light-webfont.svg#QuicksandLight') format('svg');
     /*url('/assets/fonts/Quicksand_Light.otf');*/
font-weight: lighter;
font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
font-family: 'Quicksand';
src: url('/assets/fonts/Quicksand_Light_Oblique-webfont.eot');
src: url('/assets/fonts/Quicksand_Light_Oblique-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('/assets/fonts/Quicksand_Light_Oblique-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('/assets/fonts/Quicksand_Light_Oblique-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('/assets/fonts/Quicksand_Light_Oblique-webfont.svg#QuicksandLightOblique') format('svg');
font-weight: lighter;
font-style: italic;

}

@font-face {
font-family: 'Quicksand';
src: url('/assets/fonts/Quicksand_Book-webfont.eot');
src: url('/assets/fonts/Quicksand_Book-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('/assets/fonts/Quicksand_Book-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('/assets/fonts/Quicksand_Book-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('/assets/fonts/Quicksand_Book-webfont.svg#QuicksandBook') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}
```

This means you can reference the font weight in your css rather than having to set the font as oblique. eg

```
body
{
 font: italic lighter 13px/24px 'Quicksand', Arial,sans-serif;
 }
```

That will print the font in Italic in the lighter style

Comment: its loading from another css file which has been referenced. It oes pick up the QuicksandBook but not the Light one. This is using a MAC in all browsers.